# glibmm/gtkmm custom property explanation/example request

Tags: c++, properties, getter-setter, glib, glibmm

i'm trying to reimplement a set of GLIB classes in C++ using GLIBMM.
Most of them are buggy and need to be expanded a lot and since the entire project is done in C++ i preferred to port the code before correcting it.

Unfortunately i'm not a GLIB expert and even if i've spent many days around the official documentation i'm still in trouble in understanding some concepts, expecially around Properties.

As far as i have understood, properties are a full replacement (and maybe more) for setters and getters. Basically, instead of using specialized methods for each attribute, a common set/get_property method is used for all of them, accessing the property with a name (or ID) and using a container like GValue to hold multiple kind of data.

The only advantage i can see in this is the ability to access properties with names contained in strings (which may come for example from a configuration file) but i'm surely missing something. Moreover this seems to be true in GLIB but not in Glib::ObjectBase which says that you should prefer a specialized property_(*) getter/setter instead of property_set/get_value.

Reading the documentation about Glib::Property i'm not sure how a full properties implementation in C++ should like, i presume the lack of experience with GLIB is making it harder.

I'd like to move every property as an attribute with std get/set methods but i don't want to make a lot of changes discovering too late that the previous approch was times better :)

Can someone explain me what a property is (if compared with a C++ class attribute)? Can you provide me an example of a working property with signal/slots? Can someone put some light over the advantages of the two ways?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look under the hood of Glib properties [GObject properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)
we see the c implementation at work. The above link also has a detailed explanation of the the code .

> Object properties
>
> "One of GObject's nice features is its generic get/set mechanism for object properties. When an object is instantiated, the object's class_init handler should be used to register the object's properties with g_object_class_install_properties.

A more detail explanation  in C++ and C can be found in both the links.

The best way to understand how object properties work is by looking at a real example of how it is used:

If we look at [Glib Property details](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1Property.html#details) we can see

> A **Glib::Object property.**
>
> "This **class wraps a GObject property**, providing a **C++ API** to the GObject property system, for use with classes derived from Glib::Object or Glib::Interface.
>
> A property is a value associated with each instance of a type and some class data for each property:
>
> 1. Its unique name, used to identify the property.
> 2. A human-readable nick name.
> 3. A short description.
> 4. The default value and the minimum and maximum bounds (depending on the type of the property).
> 5. Flags, defining, among other things, whether the property can be read or written."

Example Ref [GObject properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)

```
class MyCellRenderer : public Gtk::CellRenderer
{
public:
MyCellRenderer()
:
Glib::ObjectBase (typeid(MyCellRenderer)),
Gtk::CellRenderer(),
```

> The Equivalent of type definition in C or C++ (Constructor / Destructor)
>
> Template  Glib::Property< T >::Property  (   Glib::Object&   object,
>           const Glib::ustring&    name 
>       )

**mybool  is the name** and **true is the default value**

> property_mybool (*this, "mybool", true),
>
> property_myint_  (*this, "myint", 42)

```
{}
virtual ~MyCellRenderer() {}
```

// Glib::Property<> can be public,

**  Declaration of type constructor / destructor Eg Public or private**

```
Glib::Property<bool> property_mybool;
// or private, and combined with Glib::PropertyProxy<>.
Glib::PropertyProxy<int> property_myint() { return property_myint_.get_proxy(); }
private:
Glib::Property<int> property_myint_;
};
```

both **g_object_set_property** and **class_init handler** may be of use to you Ref  [GObject properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)

All the best

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i've tried to complete porting the code in C++ but the relative versions of the bindings are partially incomplete, making it just a mess!